# Change pandas dataframe column value depending on other columns values having three options

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a **Pandas** dataframe with a column named `col1`, and I want to add a new column to the dataframe, which value depends on the content of `col1` for each record. I tried this:

`d['new_column'] = 'CASE 1' if d['COL1'] == None else 'CASE 2' if d['COL1'] == 0 else 'CASE 3'`

But I got this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How can I make the evaluation to set the values of the new column properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). It's efficient and easy to use for this cases:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_column'] = np.where(d['COL1'].isnull(), 'CASE1',
                            np.where(d['COL1']==0, 'CASE 2', 'CASE 3'))
```